# Request to reopen a question

Tags: discussion

I don't do this often, but can [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/416632/58761) question please be reopened? The question now shows the required research. It might be a better fit on ELL, but it would need to be reopened to be migrated.

[What's the difference between “to my mind”, “in my opinion” and “in my view”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/416632/58761)

It's not that it's a great question or has interesting connotations (well, connotations are always interesting to me), or is a really deserving question. It just meets the criteria now.

Thanks for considering.

Comment: Done and done. And done.

Comment: So many thanks! Much kindness on this site, @NVZ :)

Comment: ELU seems to be developing an 'Interpersonal Skills' culture @anongoodnurse!

Comment: The user cross posted to [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/146174/41273) while their question was closed, though. :(